# How can I open launchpad on 2020 Macbook air?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

My last macbook had a dedicated key (f4) for open launchpad. On my new macbook, the f4 key opens search instead of launchpad.

Is there are way I can open launchpad quickly with a keyboard shoutcut, without using some contorted trackpad gesture?

Comment: Edit a shortcut in system preferences : keyboard?

Answer (score 3):

You can set it to whatever you want in **System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts**:

[image: Keyboard shortcut preferences]

Comment: Cody, how are you able to set it up like that? F4 doesn't seem to be accepted: I press it and it doesn't register--the box remains empty. Thanks!

Comment: @Sergio Did you try Fn-F4? If this also doesn't work, please ask a new question.